# Dynamically replace variables to vars (makefile awk)

Tags: regex, awk, makefile, environment-variables

In my Makefile i have some recipes like

```
start-$(PARAM_NAME): ## Comment 1
do some things...
stop-$(PARAM_NAME): ## Comment 2
do some things
```

I want use recipe help, that can parse file and print info like

```
start-name    Starts...
stop-name     Stops
```

PARAM_NAME == name
All PARAM_NAME i got from config file with key=value structure (like env file)

Makefile recipe

```
help:
    @awk 'BEGIN {FS=":.*?## "} /^[A-z-]*(.\([A-z]*\))?[A-z-]*:.*?## / {printf "\033[36m-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
```

This take line with comment, explode to Name and Comment, but in name there is start-$(PARAM_NAME). I want replace $(PARAM_NAME) to its variable (name).

Comment: figure out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do outside of a makefile first, THEN figure out how to call that script in a makefile. btw I'm not sure what you think `":.*?## "` means but whatever it is, it doesn't mean that....

Answer (score 0):

if you use shell variables in the standard form `$VARIABLE` or `${VARIABLE}` there is a command that will do the parameter substitution.

```
$ envsubst <file | awk -F':.*## ' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1 {print $1,$2}'

start-name      Comment 1
stop-name       Comment 2
```

of course change the `NF>1` to some filtering if this is printing more than you want.  Add colors for flavor... :)